# How do I configure apache-traffic-server to forward an http request to an https remote server?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apache-traffic-server

I have an esp8266 which was directly sending http requests to `http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` but since google seems have stopped allowing requests to be send via http,  I need to find a new solution.

I started down a path to have the esp8266 directly send the request via https and while it works on a small example the memory footprint required for the https request is to much in my full application and I end up crashing the esp8266.  While there are still some avenues to explore that might allow me to continue to directly send messages to the server,  I think I would like to solve this by sending the request via http to a local "server" raspberry pi,  and have that send the request via https.

While I could run a small web server and some code to do handle the requests, it seems like this is exactly something traffic-server should be able to do for me.

I thought this should be a one liner.  I added the following the the `remap.config` file.

`redirect http://192.168.86.77/fcm/send https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

where `192.168.86.77` is the local address of my raspberry pi.

When I send requests to `http://192.168.86.77/fcm/send:8080` I get back the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 20 Sep 2019 16:22:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian)
Content-Length: 288
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /fcm/send:8080 was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I think 8080 is the right port.
I am guessing this is not the one liner I thought it should be.

Is this a good fit for apache-traffic-controller?
Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong and what is the right way to accomplish my goal?

### Update:

Based on Miles Libbey answer below,  I needed to make the following update to the Arduino/esp8266 code.

Change:

```
http_.begin("http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
```

To:

```
http_.begin("192.168.86.77", 8080, "http://192.168.86.77/fcm/send");
```

where http_ is the instance of the HTTPClient

And after installing [trafficserver](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/index.html#) on the my raspberry pi, I needed to add the following two lines to the `/etc/trafficserver/remap.config`

```
map http://192.168.86.77/fcm/send https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
reverse_map https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send http://192.168.86.77/fcm/send
```

Note the `reverse_map` line is only needed if you want to get feedback from fcm, ie if the post was successful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a few changes:
- I'd use map:
`map http://192.168.86.77/fcm/send https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` instead of redirect. The `redirect` is meant to send your client a 301, and then your client would follow it, which sounds like it'd defeat your purpose. map should have ATS do the proxying.
- I think your curl may have been off  -- the port usually goes after the domain part -- eg, `curl "http://192.168.86.77:8080/fcm/send"`. (and probably better:
`curl -x 192.168.86.77:8080 "http://192.168.86.77:8080/fcm/send"`, so that the port isn't part of the remapping.